# When LWC invokes a function, is it possible for the function to access arbitrary attributes in the invoking element?

Tags: lightning-web-components, data, lightning-events, parameters, attribute

Let's say my LWC has the following code:

```
<c-widget-tile widget={widget} onwidgetselect={openWidget}></c-widget-tile>
```

Assuming `widget` contains the data for an instance of `Widget__c` Is it possible for my openWidget function to get `widget.Id` out of the `event` parameter?

(I know I can make this work by including `data-record-id={widget.Id}` in the `c-widget` and then getting the value out of `event.target.dataset.recordId`, but I'd prefer to make the solution less redundant and more concise.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your widget-tile component can include the widget passed in to it:

```
@api widget;
dispatchWidgetSelectEvent() {
    this.dispatchEvent(
        new CustomEvent('widgetselect', { detail: { widget } })
    );
}
```

Given that code in the widget tile, you can then:

```
openWidget(event) {
    let widgetId = event.detail.widget.Id;
    // ... //
}
```

---

You can also access the widget via the API property for the component:

```
 openWidget(event) {
     let widgetId = event.target.widget.Id;
 }
```